# Linux utility for a one time copy via HTTP

Tags: linux

Help me here.

I once used a utility (written in Python, I think), that is for sharing files across machines using HTTP.

It creates a tiny web server + URL which is good for one single GET request only, then it shuts down.

This allows you to GET a file from another machine using HTTP.

Please can anyone tell me what this command is?

Comment: I vaguely remember reading about something like this.  But for the life of me, I cannot remember the name of the program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you talking about [**woof**](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/woof.html)?

Comment: Rock on.  Cheers :)

Comment: http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/woof.html

Answer (score 6):

Actually you don't need anything except Python to do that.

```
cd dir/to/share
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This way you can access dir/to/share through http://HOSTNAME/. To stop sharing just CTRL+C.

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer's default port is 8000, so I guess it would be  http://HOSTNAME:8000/ . Simple and very useful !

Comment: Yes, that is right. You can also specify a different port as the last argument, eg.

python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7999

will listen on port 7999

Answer (score 1):

I would still like to show you this project called [quickserve](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/info/quickserve).  It seems to improve upon the ideas of woof.  from the CLI you can have it share a file or directory, generate a random username/password, http server and URL.  You can even set the '-u' flag and enable an upload to your web server. Its only make depend is python.

Answer (score 1):

And if you don't have Python? Use NetCat.